# How do I get these DOM element names right in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need create a page that has many repetitive forms that will update some divs on the page. Imagine a long list of books labeled "Book 1", "Book 2", etc. where you have to click a link to see the name of any given book. There will be hundreds. I want to use a single script to do it. I think I have it all figured out but I am not clear how to call two of the DOM elements. Note I am using jQuery (for reasons that don't have anything to do with this question, just trust that I have to use it). Here is my code with comments where I need help:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
      src="/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Book 1</p>
    <form id="form001">
      <input type="hidden" name="book" value="Stranger In A Strange Land" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="output001"></div>

    <p>Book 2</p>
    <form id="form002">
      <input type="hidden" name="book" value="I, Robot" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="output002"></div>

    <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
      $j( "form" ).submit(function ( )
      {


        var book = ???;        //  <========= What do I put here???
        var formName = ???;    //  <========= What do I put here???


        // Below I extract the form number (e.g. “001” from “form001”) and
        // tack it on to the div name I am repopulating
        var outputDiv = '#output' + substr( formName, formName.length - 3, 3 ); 

        $j(outputDiv).html(book);
      }); 
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like you are going for a too complicated design for your problem. When ever I see multiple forms to be submitted like this, I always wonder can't I find a more elegant, simpler solution.

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to output the book name (e.g. `Stranger In A Strange Land`) to the ouput div with the appropriate ID (e.g. `div#output001`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

  $j( "form" ).submit(function (event) {
    // event is the form-submission event, which we
    // (probably) want to cancel, which we do by calling:
    event.preventDefault();

    // 'this' is the current <form> that's being submitted,
    // we look within that <form> to find the <input> element
    // with a name equal to 'book', and retrieve its value:
    var book = $j(this).find('input[name=book]').val();

    // we get the id of the <form> here:
    var formName = this.id;

    // here we select the appropriate element by replacing
    // the 'form' with 'output', and constructing an id-selector:
    $j('#' + formName.replace('form', 'output')).html(book);
  });
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).
  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
  - [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).